# How to set geckodriver in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am getting some error with selenium python in pycharm when I am trying to create a firefox driver for me.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox("C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe")
```

Here the path is correct but I am getting the below error. Can anyone help please.

```
WindowsError: [Error 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe/*.*'
```

Can anyone please help me.
My python version is 2.7.14

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Actually I got the answer. I should have written it like this.

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\Users\\Vivek\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win32\\geckodriver.exe") 

I was missing "executable_path"

Comment: Oh right yeah, my bad, the other question was for setting the firefox binary.